# Enforcing terms and condition Agreement in Android?

Tags: android

How to enforce terms and condition agreement in Android? I want to do it like this http://www.droidbin.com/. You can observe in the given link that upload appears only when checkbox is ticked else it invisible and initially it is invisible.

My login XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/startbg"
                android:padding="0dip"
                tools:context=".LoginActivity">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
            android:paddingRight="40dp">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:text="Enter your number"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="@color/sinch_purple" android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/loginNo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:digits="0123456789"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:textSize="32sp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/sinch_purple"
                android:background="@drawable/inputbox">


            <requestFocus/>
        </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/button_login"
            android:minHeight="56dp"
            android:minWidth="132dp"
            android:textColor="@color/off_white"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/terms"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/sinch_purple"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/checkBox1"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Login Java file

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        String checkBoxText = "I agree to all the <a href='http://www.redbus.in/mob/mTerms.aspx' > Terms and Conditions</a>";

        mBox.setText(Html.fromHtml(checkBoxText));
        mBox.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

        //terms=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.terms);
        mLoginNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginNo);

        mLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        mLoginButton.setEnabled(false);
        mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loginClicked();
            }
        });
        mBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
            {
                if ( mBox.isChecked() )
                {
                    mLoginButton.setVisibility(buttonView.VISIBLE);
                }
                else{
                    mLoginButton.setVisibility(buttonView.GONE);
                   // terms.setText("Please Agree to Terms And Condition");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a CheckBox. Simply add the Checkbox in your layout's .xml file using XML tag `<CheckBox/>`.

Then add an OnCheckedChangeListener to the CheckBox:

```
CheckBox checkBox = null;//get the view using findViewById
    final View invisibleView = null;//do the same
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                invisibleView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else
                invisibleView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Excellent but i already did it 
<Button android:visibility="gone"/>
<checkbox> tag
and in acitivity
mBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(mBox.isChecked()){
                    mLoginButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else{
                    mLoginButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

Comment: What's the problem then?

Comment: though i didn't use CompundButton can you tell me what is the use of it ?

Comment: Problem resolved i applied the same thing as you did instead i didn't used CompoundButton

Answer (score 0):

See what I did in XML:

```
    <Button
                android:id="@+id/loginButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/button_login"
                android:minHeight="56dp"
                android:minWidth="132dp"
                android:textColor="@color/off_white"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            />
```

And in Java file

```
private Button mLoginButton;
    private EditText mLoginNo;
    private ProgressDialog mSpinner;
    private CheckBox mBox;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        mBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        String checkBoxText = "I agree to all the <a href='http://www.redbus.in/mob/mTerms.aspx' > Terms and Conditions</a>";

        mBox.setText(Html.fromHtml(checkBoxText));
        mBox.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        mLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        mBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(mBox.isChecked()){
                    mLoginButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else{
                    mLoginButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

        mLoginNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginNo);


        mLoginButton.setEnabled(false);
        mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loginClicked();
            }
        });
    }
```